# When reading json in spark, convert a single value to array

Tags: json, apache-spark

Json can have either a single value or an array of multiple values as a property value. E.g., `"A":"ae"` or `"A":["ab", "cd"]`
When I read json-nd files (each line is a json), my target property may have a single value or an array of the same type value.

I need to use `explode()` to get the data. but when a single value is shown, then `explode()` complains.

So, my question is how to make all values of a certain property become an array in spark dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values are scalars you can use `array` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

array(col("A")).alias("A")

spark.read.json(
  Seq("""{"A": "ae"}""").toDS).select(array(col("A")).alias("A")
).show
// +----+
// |   A|
// +----+
// |[ae]|
// +----+
```

If values are mixed, you have parse things manually:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

Seq("""{"A": "ae"}""", """{"A": ["ab", "cd"]}""").toDS.select(coalesce(
    // Attempt to parse value as array<string>
    from_json($"value", StructType.fromDDL("A array<string>"))("A"),
    // If the first one fails, try to extract it as string and enclose with array
    array(get_json_object($"value", "$.A"))
).alias("A")).show

// +--------+
// |       A|
// +--------+
// |    [ae]|
// |[ab, cd]|
// +--------+
```

If you use older Spark version replace:

```
 StructType.fromDDL("A array<string>")
```

with

```
StructType(Seq(StructField("A", ArrayType(StringType))))
```

Comment: Looks like you use older version of Spark.

Comment: I got an error: `error: not found: value from_json
    from_json($"value", StructType(Seq(StructField("A", ArrayType(StringType)))))("A"),
    ^` Do you know any old version of from_json()?

Comment: There isn't one. You could create an udf, but if you use that old Spark version (2.0 or earlier) it is really time for update.

Comment: I've just checked in my spark-shell it works fine with your first solution. Thank you. Just one more question: what is the meaning of `"$.A"` ?